# cucumber-jvm: compare datatables ignoring certain columns

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I want to compare a DataTable from feature file against one on page, but want to ignore certain date time fields. Is there a straight way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Missing fields are ignored when comparing a DataTable against a list of objects, e.g.:

```
static class SomeBean {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;

    public SomeBean(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }
}

    DataTable expectationBeanTable = DataTable.create(Arrays.asList(
            new SomeBean("value1", "value2", null)
    ));

    List<SomeBean> actual = Arrays.asList(
            new SomeBean("value1", "value2", "value3")
    );
    expectationBeanTable.diff(actual); //OK

    DataTable expectationStringTable = DataTable.create(Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("field1", "field2"),
            Arrays.asList("value1", "value2")
    ));

    expectationStringTable.diff(actual); //Also OK
```

Won't work when comparing two DataTables though:

```
expectationStringTable.diff(DataTable.create(actual));

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tables must have equal number of columns:
      | field1 | field2 |
      | value1 | value2 |

      | field1 | field2 | field3 |
      | value1 | value2 | value3 |
```